# Update nested object using positional-filters on different levels - MongoDb update

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Considering I have the following collection (ignoring documents `_id`):

### Collection

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Level2": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1",
        "Level3": [
          {
            "Id": "1.1.1",
            "Level3_4": {
              "Transport": "Car",
              "Level4": [
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.1",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "N"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.2",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "S"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.3",
                  "Status": "pause",
                  "Direction": "S"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.4",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "W"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "Id": "1.1.2",
            "Level3_4": {
              "Transport": "Bus",
              "Level4": [
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.1",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "S"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.2",
                  "Status": "stop",
                  "Direction": "N"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.3",
                  "Status": "stop",
                  "Direction": "W"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.4",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "E"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Id": "1.2",
        "Level3": [
          {
            "Id": "1.2.1",
            "Level3_4": {
              "Transport": "Train",
              "Level4": [
                {
                  "Id": "1.2.1.1",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "N"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "Id": "1.2.2",
            "Level3_4": {
              "Transport": "Bus",
              "Level4": []
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

---

### Update

**I want to update all documents in the collection such as:**

- `Level2.Level3.Level3_4.Level4.Status: "pause"`

*Using `updateOne` and without upsert*

*All `Level4` that match the next conditions*

---

### Conditions

**where:**

- `Level2.Level3.Id $in ["1.1.1","1.1.2"]` **AND**
- `Level2.Level3.Level3_4.Level4.Status $in ["run", "stop"]` **AND**
- `Level2.Level3.Level3_4.Level4.Direction $in ["N", "S"]`

---

### RESULT

**The result collection should be:**

```
[
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "Level2": [
      {
        "Id": "1.1",
        "Level3": [
          {
            "Id": "1.1.1",
            "Level3_4": {
              "Transport": "Car",
              "Level4": [
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.1",
                  "Status": "pause",
                  "Direction": "N"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.2",
                  "Status": "pause",
                  "Direction": "S"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.3",
                  "Status": "pause",
                  "Direction": "S"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.1.4",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "W"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "Id": "1.1.2",
            "Level3_4": {
              "Transport": "Bus",
              "Level4": [
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.1",
                  "Status": "pause",
                  "Direction": "S"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.2",
                  "Status": "pause",
                  "Direction": "N"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.3",
                  "Status": "stop",
                  "Direction": "W"
                },
                {
                  "Id": "1.1.2.4",
                  "Status": "run",
                  "Direction": "E"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      } ... 
    ]
  }
]
```

---

I'm struggling with the `$set` operator and `arrayFilters`. How can I accomplish this?

---

This is where I went so far:

```
db.test.update({},
    {
        $set: {
            "Level2.$[level2].Level3.$[level3].Level3_4.Level4.$[level4].Status": "pause"
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                "level3.Id": {
                    $in: [
                        "1.1.1",
                        "1.1.2"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "level4.Status": {
                    $in: [
                        "run",
                        "stop"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "level4.Direction": {
                    $in: [
                        "N",
                        "S"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

However it doesn't work... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there :)

Just the issue was with the last array filter and in `$set`

I have Updated the query:

```
db.session.update(
    {},
    {
        $set: {
            "Level2.$[].Level3.$[level3].Level3_4.Level4.$[level4].Status": "pause"
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {
                "level3.Id": {
                    $in: [
                        "1.1.1",
                        "1.1.2"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "level4.Status": {
                    $in: [
                        "run",
                        "stop"
                    ]
                },
                "level4.Direction": {
                    $in: [
                        "N",
                        "S"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Hope this will help :)